# Keeping intermediate results of function composition

Tags: scala, function, composition

Suppose I've got the following three functions:

```
 val f1: Int => Option[String] = ???
 val f2: String => Option[Int] = ???
 val f3: Int => Option[Int]    = ???
```

I can compose them as follows:

```
 val f: Int => Option[Int] = x =>
   for {
     x1 <- f1(x)
     x2 <- f2(x1)
     x3 <- f3(x2)
   } yield x3
```

Suppose now that I need to keep the intermediate results of execution `f1`, `f2`, `f3` and pass them to the caller:

```
class Result(x: Int) {
  val r1 = f1(x)
  val r2 = r1 flatMap f2
  val r3 = r2 flatMap f3
  def apply = r3 
}

val f: Int => Result = x => new Result(x)
```

Does it make sense ? How would you improve/simplify this solution ?

Comment: Do you need the intermediate results in the failure case as well, or just if the entire chain succeeds?

Comment: I need the intermediate result for the failures mostly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Homogenous List

It's pretty simple for single type, suppose

```
val g1: Int => Option[Int] = x => if (x % 2 == 1) None else Some(x / 2)
val g2: Int => Option[Int] = x => Some(x * 3 + 1)
val g3: Int => Option[Int] = x => if (x >= 4) Some(x - 4) else None
```

You can define

```
def bind[T]: (Option[T], T => Option[T]) => Option[T] = _ flatMap _
def chain[T](x: T, fs: List[T => Option[T]]) = fs.scanLeft(Some(x): Option[T])(bind)
```

And now

```
chain(4, g1 :: g2 :: g3 :: Nil)
```

will be

> List(Some(4), Some(2), Some(7), Some(3))

preserving all intermediate values.

#### Heterogenous List

But we can do if there are multiple types involved?

Fortunately there is [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library for special structures named [Heterogenous List](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists) which could handle list-like multi-typed sequences of values.

So suppose we have

```
import scala.util.Try

val f1: Int => Option[String] = x => Some(x.toString)
val f2: String => Option[Int] = x => Try(x.toInt).toOption
val f3: Int => Option[Int] = x => if (x % 2 == 1) None else Some(x / 2)
```

Lets define heterogenous analogues to previous functions:

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist.LeftScanner._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._

object hBind extends Poly2 {
  implicit def bind[T, G] = at[T => Option[G], Option[T]]((f, o) => o flatMap f)
}
def hChain[Z, L <: HList](z: Z, fs: L)
                         (implicit lScan: LeftScanner[L, Option[Z], hBind.type]) =
  lScan(fs, Some(z))
```

And now

```
hChain(4, f1 :: f2 :: f3 :: HNil)
```

Evaluates to

> Some(4) :: Some("4") :: Some(4) :: Some(2) :: HNil

#### Class converter

Now if you urged to save your result in some class like

```
case class Result(init: Option[Int], 
                  x1: Option[String], 
                  x2: Option[Int], 
                  x3: Option[Int])
```

You could easily use it's [`Generic` representation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes)

just ensure yourself that

```
Generic[Result].from(hChain(4, f1 :: f2 :: f3 :: HNil)) == 
  Result(Some(4),Some("4"),Some(4),Some(2))
```